# WebStorm ignore jslint maxlen comment

Tags: webstorm, jslint

I'm evaluating WebStorm 11 and I have a problem with the `/*jslint maxlen: 130, nomen: true */` comment only the `maxlen` doesn't work:

[image: jslint error]

Also the git code analysis return the same errors only for the `maxlen` too:

[image: jslint error 2]

What am I missing here?
I looked into the [WebStorm jslint docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/jslint.html) but couldn't find anything about this.